# Html page jumps when clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Building a frontend and getting a bit baffled since I´m unable to stop the browser to jump when triggering a click event on an img.

I thought that either event.preventDefault() or return false would do it but I am obviously missing something and is completely at a loss about what to try next!

Here is the code

```
    $("#imgViewer-thumbs").find("img").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $imgViewPane = $("#imgViewPane"),
                $selectedImage = $imgViewPane.find(".selected-image"),
                $clickedImage = $(this),
                $clickedImageIndex = $clickedImage.prevAll().length + 1,
                $maxIndex = $clickedImageIndex + $clickedImage.nextAll().length,
                $targetImage = $imgViewPane.find(":nth-child(" + $clickedImageIndex + ")");

        if (!$targetImage.hasClass("selected-image")) {
            $selectedImage.fadeOut(100, function () {
                $targetImage.addClass("selected-image");
                $selectedImage.removeClass("selected-image");
                $targetImage.fadeIn(100);
            });
        }
        console.log('Returning false');
        return false;
    }
    );
```

EDIT:
Setup the imageviewer in jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tEXaa/

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: Post relevant html code of your image/link.

Comment: @JacobAmerz I´ll try and setup one of those.

Comment: Please don't change the question by editing in the solution. It invalidates the answer and makes everything confusing.

Comment: Ok, I´ll change it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that image container `"#imgViewPane"` doen't hold the height. So then the prev image fades out `"#imgViewPane"` loses height and as a result the page loses scroll position.

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tEXaa/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with clicking anchor tags, and the problem wasn't with any jquery code but with negative margins.

Instead of using something like this

```
<div width="600px">
   <div id="top-left" style="height:200px;"> some content </div>
   <div id="top-right" style="margin-top:-200px;> content"</div>
</div>
```

use

```
<div width="600px">
   <div id="top-left" style="float:left;"> some content </div>
   <div id="top-right" style="float:right;> content"</div>
</div>
```